# How to redirect in order to get a clean url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like to redirect `http://example.com/video.php?id=123A_BC` to `http://example.com/video/123A_BC` in .htaccess file by using mod_rewrite.

Comment: I have tried the following code. It did what I need but the query string also added to the end of url

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/video\.php$`
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$`
`RewriteRule ^(.*) video/%1 [R=301,L]`

the output is this http://example.com/video/ABC_123?id=ABC_123

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rewrite instead of redirecting for clean url.

Please try this,

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi, it does not work for me. I just need to replace .php?id= with /

Comment: Here when you call `http://example.com/video/123A_BC` it is internally rewriting request to `http://example.com/video.php?id=123A_BC` please check

Comment: my original link is http://example.com/video.php?id=123A_BC and I want to replace it with http://example.com/video/123A_BC

Comment: yes that is what i am doing what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I understand that the second and third lines a conditions that check if the original file not exist and only if it true the rewrite rule will be processed. Since the original file is still exist, I commented the second and third lines but still the RewriteRule is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The following code solved my problem

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/video\.php$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) video/%1? [R=301,L]
```